# Google Maps requests failing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using the gmaps4rails gem to draw markers on Google Maps.

It's working fine except for a tiny detail: the Developer Tools console is showing a lot of failed requests:

```
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:1.410227%2C103.849125,sp:0.06864x0.13733,src:apiv3,ts:nazjhi  VM2213:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DE_POGazYMv3%26z%3D13&cad=src:apiv3,ts:nazjiy  VM2213:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DGGFIXwX55eI%26z%3D13&cad=src:apiv3,ts:nazjku  VM2213:2
```

I wasn't sure if it's my fault or gmaps4rails', so I went looking at their [samples page](http://apneadiving.github.io/) and was greeted by a storm of errors:

```
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:0%2C0,sp:1.64789x6.25122,src:apiv3,ts:nar16j  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:0%2C0,sp:1.64789x6.25122,src:apiv3,ts:nar16u  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:0%2C0,sp:1.64789x6.25122,src:apiv3,ts:nar16z  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:0%2C0,sp:1.64789x6.25122,src:apiv3,ts:nar172  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:0%2C0,sp:1.64789x6.25122,src:apiv3,ts:nar177  VM456:2
...
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DDrUstzDkra5,MioK6k6FoP…ryQNw,KJaIHv5kEQX,M_PFtL6x9ap,HOzAaWorA9R%26z%3D15&cad=src:apiv3,ts:nar4al  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DNWkU-iIxLP5,PVvHSIe22T…cNJQIr,BfOy-lwIId,GbCjuFKSUZo,GGjY6a2AiaE%26z%3D15&cad=src:apiv3,ts:nar4cc  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:41.896837%2C-87.749474,sp:0.61332x3.12561,src:apiv3,ts:nar52b  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DLlNRGH16trt%26z%3D15&cad=src:apiv3,ts:nar5td  VM456:2
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DFocoOsrnywU,DOrlfnWXQcO,LGE7D7W4MJf,Kz78zqn9woS,PH54idy16yE%26z%3D9&cad=src:apiv3,ts:nar7cr  VM456:2
```

Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: I dont know what you;re talking about I have no error on the sample page

Comment: I fear you are confused by standard google maps calls to retrieve map, those are logs not errors

Comment: They were showing as 'failed', with no response received. But I think it might have been a crappy connection or Google limiting me as I don't see the errors anymore. Thanks for a quick response anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Those files also fail for me, but it's because [AdBlockPlus](https://adblockplus.org/) is actively blocking them. I have the following rule in my [EasyPrivacy list](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.txt) (although there are potentially more that likewise match):

```
||googleapis.com^*/gen_204?
```

Comment: This seems likely to be part of the problem. I also have AdBlock Plus with EasyList. But I haven't seen these errors since posting here, so there must be something else going on as well.